# Use index(of:) on Array of Protocol Type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

For adding more flexibility inside my mostly static tableViews, I have a protocol defined like this:

```
protocol StaticSection {
    static var active: [StaticSection] { get }
    // func cell(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell
    // var numberOfRows: Int { get }
}

extension StaticSection: Equatable {
    static func at(_ index: Int) -> StaticSection {
        return active[index]
    }

    static func index(ofSection section: StaticSection) -> Int {
        return active.index(of: section) // Not working :(
    }
}
```

Which I use like this

```
enum MySections: StaticSection {
    case header, footer, sectionA, sectionB

    static var active: [StaticSection] {
        // Here I can dynamically enable/disable/rearrange sections
        return [MySections.header, .footer]
    }
}
```

In the `enum` implementation of the protocol I can access the index of a section like this:

```
(StaticSections.active as! [MySections]).index(of: .header)
```

Now I want to implement the `index(ofSection section: StaticSection)` in the extension to have a more convenient way to do this.
I tried it like shown above in the extension. But I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: StaticSection)'

Is this even possible in Swift?

Comment: Shouldn't your parameter be of type `MySections` ? So maybe you should try casting the value of `StaticSection` to `MySection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
protocol StaticSection {
    static var active: [Self] { get } // note the change to Self
    // func cell(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell
    // var numberOfRows: Int { get }
}

extension StaticSection where Self : Equatable { // another change here
    static func at(_ index: Int) -> Self {
        return active[index]
    }

    static func index(ofSection section: Self) -> Int? {
        return active.index(of: section)
    }
}

enum MySections: StaticSection {
    case header, footer, sectionA, sectionB

    static var active: [MySections] { // note the change to MySections
        // Here I can dynamically enable/disable/rearrange sections
        return [.header, .footer]
    }
}
```

The important thing to note here is this syntax:

```
where Self : Equatable
```

This means that the extension only applies to types that conforms to `StaticSection` and `Equatable`, whereas this:

```
: Equatable
```

will make `StaticSection` inherit from `Equatable`, which you cannot do in Swift.

Comment: `: Equatable will make StaticSection inherit from Equatable, which you cannot do in Swift.`: `StaticSection` and `Equatable` are both protocols. Wouldn’t it just add the requirements of `Equatable` to `StaticSection`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Purpose I mean you can’t make a protocol inherit from another in an extension

Comment: .. and making it conditional conformance does not make additional restrictions on the primary protocol, since it only adds the extension incase Self is equatable. Smart!

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I did not know that using `Self` inside protocols like this is allowed :)